I need to upload extension using exe file, but unable to due to drivers issues
I have a extension which is working fine if upload seprately on each browser, but i want to automate it and want to upload extension on following browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) by using the exe file.
For that i have created a simple node project which is responsible for creating an exe, and in that folder i have a extension folder (which contains the whole extension code). I am sharing my package.json and my main js file which is install-extension.js
package.json
{
  "name": "extension-installer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Installer for browser extension",
  "main": "install-extension.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node install-extension.js"
  },
 "bin": "install-extension.js",
 "author": "Noman Zahid",
 "license": "ISC",
 "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "dist/*",
      "selenium/**/*",
      "manifest_chrome.json",
      "manifest_firefox.json",
      "drivers/chromedriver.exe",
      "drivers/geckodriver.exe",
      "drivers/msedgedriver.exe",
      "node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/*",
      "node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/**/*",
      "node_modules/webdriver-manager/config.json",
      "node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/**/*"
    ],
    "targets": [
      "node14-win-x64"
    ],
    "outputPath": "dist"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "chromedriver": "^127.0.1",
   "edgedriver": "^5.6.0",
   "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
   "geckodriver": "^4.4.2",
   "open": "^10.1.0",
   "pkg": "^5.8.1",
   "selenium-webdriver": "^4.23.0",
   "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.9"
 }
}

Here is my install-extension.js code
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const isPkg = typeof process.pkg !== 'undefined';
const baseDir = isPkg ? path.dirname(process.execPath) : __dirname;
const driverDir = path.join(baseDir, 'selenium', 'webdriver-manager');

const CHROME_MANIFEST = path.join(baseDir, 'manifest_chrome.json');
const FIREFOX_MANIFEST = path.join(baseDir, 'manifest_firefox.json');
const MANIFEST_FILE = 'manifest.json';
const BROWSERS = ['chrome', 'firefox', 'edge'];

function copyFile(source, destination) {
    return fs.copy(source, destination)
    .then(() => console.log(`Copied ${source} to ${destination}`))
    .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to copy ${source} to ${destination}:`, err));
}

function openURL(browser, url) {
    let driver;
    try {
        if (browser === 'chrome') {
            driver = new Builder()
                .forBrowser('chrome')
                .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=9222'))
                .setChromeService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path.join(driverDir, 'chromedriver.exe')))
                .build();
        } else if (browser === 'firefox') {
            driver = new Builder()
                .forBrowser('firefox')
                .setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options())
                .setFirefoxService(new firefox.ServiceBuilder(path.join(driverDir, 'geckodriver.exe')))
                .build();
        } else if (browser === 'edge') {
            driver = new Builder()
                .forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge')
                .setEdgeOptions(new edge.Options())
                .setEdgeService(new edge.ServiceBuilder(path.join(driverDir, 'msedgedriver.exe')))
                .build();
        } else {
            console.error(`Unsupported browser: ${browser}`);
            return;
        }

        driver.get(url).then(() => console.log(`Opened ${browser}`));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Failed to open ${browser}:`, err);
    } finally {
        if (driver) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}

function installExtension(browser) {
    let sourceManifest;
    if (browser === 'chrome' || browser === 'edge') {
        sourceManifest = CHROME_MANIFEST;
    } else if (browser === 'firefox') {
        sourceManifest = FIREFOX_MANIFEST;
    } else {
        console.error(`Unsupported browser: ${browser}`);
        return;
    }

    const tempDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `extension-${browser}`);
    const destinationManifest = path.join(tempDir, MANIFEST_FILE);

    fs.mkdirpSync(tempDir); // Ensure the directory exists

    copyFile(sourceManifest, destinationManifest).then(() => {
        console.log(`Installing extension for ${browser}`);
        if (browser === 'chrome') {
            openURL('chrome', 'chrome://extensions');
        } else if (browser === 'firefox') {
            openURL('firefox', 'about:addons');
        } else if (browser === 'edge') {
            openURL('edge', 'edge://extensions/');
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(`Failed to install extension for ${browser}:`, err);
    });
}

console.log('Starting extension installation process');

BROWSERS.forEach(browser => {
    console.log(`Installing for ${browser}`);
    installExtension(browser);
});

console.log('Finished extension installation process');

When executing the .exe file getting this type of errors,

some time it referes to a version but for that i am now using a "webdriver-manager", but still no success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated...

ENOENT means those files don't exist. Do they? I don't know the webdriver-manager but I guess you're expecting it to supply the missing files? How are you configuring / running the manager?

I have installed this package in my node.js server, and it contain the drivers for browsers. and in node_modules, where this package is installed contatins the files which are necessary for this script.

OK, but your code isn't looking in node_modules, it's looking in dist. So I guess you need to work out how to get them copied into dist, or you need to get the code to look in node_modules instead (if you're always going to be running it from a  build tree)

Yes you are right, basically i have added same in dist to avoid the ENOENT. But i guess copying file while executing maybe the best way.
